# aggregating a sparse matrix by colnames as dates

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate, sparse-matrix

I have a really large sparse matrix with the frequency of different words over 3 years for each day. The matrix just contains the frequency of the word on that day, so the rownames are actually the word and the colnames are the dates from 2014-01-01 to 2017-12-31. I want to aggregate the matrix by months, so my idea was to cut the day from the dates of, so I get the same colname for each month, but I don't know how to properly sum them up. As for aggregating in weeks I have no clue how to do it. I saw it is relatively easy to aggregate in dataframes but I don't want to transform my matrix cause it's really big, like 2gb. I also read about plyr but dont know how to really make use of it. I also know about Matrix.utils aggregate.Matrix, but I dont understand the documentation about the groupings operator at all. I hope this makes sense.

the Matrix looks like this:

```
      2014-01-01  2014-01-02  2014-01-03  2014-01-04  ...
 a    4           5           .           20          ...
 b    .           .           45          .           ...
 c    2           2           13          87          ...
 d    2           .           87          12          ...
 .    .           .           .           .           .
 .    .           .           .           .           .
```

The matrix is calles sparse.freq and as pointed out by @Georgery I did renamed the colnames with following line

```
colnames(sparse.freq) <- substr(colnames(sparse.freq), 1, 7)
```

This cuts the days from the dates and just leave the year and the months, then I used sapply to go through the matrix and sum up the values.

```
sparse.freq.months <- sapply(
    unique(colnames(sparse.freq))
    , function(x, sparse.freq) rowSums(sparse.freq[,colnames(sparse.freq) == x])
    , sparse.freq = sparse.freq)
```

For weeks I now tried rename the columns from the original matrix to year and week using

```
myDates <- colnames(sparse.freq)
myWeeks <- paste(year(myDates), week(myDates))
colnames(sparse.freq) <- myWeeks
```

But when I now try to do this

```
sparse.freq.weeks <- sapply(
     unique(colnames(sparse.freq))
     , function(x, sparse.freq) rowSums(sparse.freq[,colnames(sparse.freq) == x])
     , sparse.freq = sparse.freq)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 'x' must be a array with at least two dimensions
```

Does somebody know why, cause it's the same matrix as above it just has different named columns

Comment: Please, write a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your martix is called "a"
Rename the columns

```
# you want the first 7 characters in the date strings
colnames(a) <- substr(colnames(a), 1, 7)
```

You can sum like this

```
a <- matrix(
    c(1:10, 11:20)
    , nrow = 5
    , dimnames = list(1:5, c(1,2,1,2))
)

a

sapply(
    unique(colnames(a))
    , function(x, a) rowSums(a[,colnames(a) == x])
    , a = a)
```

For dates in general I recommend the lubridate package. If you want the weeks, first convert the column names similar to this:

```
library(lubridate)

myDates <- c("20170103", "20160103")
myDates <- ymd(myDates)
myWeeks <- paste(year(myDates), week(myDates))
```

Comment: thanks a million. that work's like a charm. Do have an idea how to archive this for each week?

Comment: Concerning the weeks I edited the post. Don't forget to edit your post, so it provides a reproducible example. ;)

Comment: Hi thank you. I edited my post and tried your suggestion for the weeks but I get an Error.

Comment: I wrote it in post too.
Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 'x' must be a array with at least two dimensions

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm sorry, but I can't see why. The Problem is that you just don't provide a reproducible example. If you do that and the error keeps coming up I can run the code on my computer and see what is happening. Right now, I can only read about some matrix on someelses computer that I don't have.